# how to create upside down bar graphs with shared x-axis with matplotlib / seaborn and a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

I want to create a graph similar to this. Is this possible using matplotlib / seaborn. If so, what resources can I use in order to learn how to style matplotlib / seaborn graphs and how can I get the two graphs to line up like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a common **x-axis** and convert one of the datasets to contain negative values.

```
y = ['{} to {} years'.format(i, i+4) for i in range(0, 90, 4)]
d_1 = np.random.randint(0, 150, 23)
d_2 = -1 * d_1
```

Then plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(y, d_1)
ax.bar(y, d_2)

# Formatting x labels
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
# Use absolute value for y-ticks
ticks =  ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels([int(abs(tick)) for tick in ticks])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And is there a way to crop the y-range? Say you want to hide an interval around zero and only show y-values > 50?